# Making an idle game in java

Tags: java

So, basiclly, I've been making a text-based game in java (it's an incemental game, like [cookie clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)), and I've ran into a problem. You see, every *other* time you type a command, you get nothing.

here is the code:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Apples {

```
public static int upQuarks = 0;
public static int downQuarks = 0;
public static int electrons = 0;

public static int protons = 0;
public static int neutrons = 0;

public static int HAtoms = 0;

public static int upQuarkCreation = 1;
public static int downQuarkCreation = 1;
public static int electronCreation = 1;

public static int protonCreation = 1;
public static int neutronCreation = 1;

public static int atomCreation = 1;

public static String question = "0";


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner dad = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {

    switch(question) {

        case "0":
            System.out.println("Welcome to this untitled text adventure game, created by Adam and Benjamin Roache.");
            System.out.println("Please enter your name.");
            question = "1";
            break;

        case "01":
            dad.next();
            question = "1A";
            break;

        case "1A":
            System.out.println("\n\nAre you sure this is your name?\n[1]Yes\n[2]No");
            switch(dad.next()) {
                case "1":
                   System.out.println("Type help to get help.");
                   question = "2";
                   break;

                case "2":
                   System.out.println("\n\n");
                   question = "0";
                   break;


            }

        case "2":
            switch(dad.next()) {
                case "help":
                    if (electrons >=1 && protons >= 1) {
                        System.out.println("\n\nTo go to the Atom Creator, type atom.");

                    }
                    if (upQuarks >= 2 && downQuarks >= 2) {
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\n\nTo create a Proton, type pro.\nTo create a Neutron, type neu.");
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("\nTo create an Up Quark, type upq.\nTo create a Down Quark, type dwnq.\nTo create a electron, type el.\nTo go to your inventory, type in.");
                    break;

                case "upq":
                    upQuarks += upQuarkCreation;
                    System.out.println("\n\nYou have 1 new Up Quark.");
                    break;

                case "dwnq":
                    downQuarks += downQuarkCreation;
                    System.out.println("\n\nYou have 1 new Down Quark.");
                    break;

                case "el":
                    electrons += electronCreation;
                    System.out.println("\n\nYou have 1 new Electron.");
                    break;

                case "pro":
                    if (upQuarks >= 2 && downQuarks >= 1) {
                        protons += protonCreation;
                        upQuarks -= 2;
                        downQuarks -= 1;
                        System.out.println("\n\nYou have 1 new proton.");
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("\n\nYou don't have those materials yet.");
                        break;
                    }

                case "neu":
                    if (downQuarks >= 2 && upQuarks >=1) {
                        neutrons += neutronCreation;
                        upQuarks -= 1;
                        downQuarks -= 2;
                        System.out.println("\n\nYou have 1 new neutron.");
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("\n\nYou don't have those materials yet.");
                        break;
                    }

                case "atom":
                    if(protons >= 1 && electrons >=1){
                        System.out.println("\n\nWelcome to the Atom Creator!");
                        question = "3";
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("\n\nYou can't acsess this yet.");
                        break;
                    }


                case "in":
                    if (protons >= 1 || neutrons >=1) {
                        System.out.println("\n\n" + protons + " protons, \n" + neutrons + " neutrons.");
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\n" + upQuarks + " up quarks, \n" + downQuarks + " down Quarks, \nand " + electrons + " electrons.");
                    break;

            }
        break;
        case "3":
            switch(dad.next()){

                case "help":
                    System.out.println("\n\nTo create an atom, type in its atomic symbol.");
                    break;

                case "H":
                    if(protons >= 1 && electrons >= 1) {
                        HAtoms += atomCreation;
                        protons -= 1;
                        electrons -= 1;
                        System.out.println("\n\nYou have created 1 new hydrogen atom.");
                        break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("You don't have the right materials.");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

the code creates these input commands:

1. "upq" = creates new Up Quark
2. "dwnq" = creates new Down Quark
3. "el" = creates new Electron
4. "pro" = creates new Proton (if, of course, you have the right mateirials.)
5. "neu" = creates new Neutron
6. "atom" = enters the Atom Creator
7. "H" = creates a hydrogen atom
8. "help" = goes to the help section.
9. "in" = enteres the inventory

   And that's all the commands.

   And this is the output:

   Welcome to this untitled text adventure game, created by Adam and Benjamin Roache.
   Please enter your name.
   Adam

Are you sure this is your name?
[1](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)Yes
[2]No
1
Type help to get help.
upq

You have 1 new Up Quark.
upq
dwnq

You have 1 new Down Quark.
in
in

1 up quarks, 
1 down Quarks, 
and 0 electrons.
upq
dwnq

You have 1 new Down Quark.
neu
neu

You have 1 new neutron.
in
in

0 protons, 
1 neutrons.

0 up quarks,
0 down quarks, 
0 electrons.

Comment: You're not calling `break;` at the end of `case "1A"`, `case "2"` and `case "3"`. And besides that, it is currently unclear what you're asking. Please provide a sample input, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: I tried adding `break;` and then there was **no** output at all!

Answer (score 0):

Use nextLine() or what it is called. Think that might be a problem